# Separate Images inside UIScrollView into sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I currently have one ImageView inside an UIScrollView which fills my whole ViewController.

This is how I set it up:

```
[imageView setImage:image];

CGSize size = [imageView sizeThatFits:imageView.frame.size];

CGSize actualSize;
actualSize.height = imageView.frame.size.height;
actualSize.width = size.width / (1.0 * (size.height / imageView.frame.size.height));

CGRect frame = imageView.frame;
frame.size = actualSize;
[imageView setFrame:frame];
```

The problem is, that I want to put multiple ImageViews (about 2 to 3) inside my ScrollView. Each section / image should also contain a title which stays at the top while scrolling to achieve an effect like in the Instragram app (the username who posted the image, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJjIH.png) or in Apple's Music application (the current letter).
Is this possible?

Comment: Look into UITableView. A table view allows you to efficiently display many items in a scrolling list (like Instagram of Music) and allows you to define your own sections by returning a string to label each section (like in Music.app) or returning your own custom view with whatever information you want (like Instagram).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arman's comment is correct - you should use a UITableView.  You will need to create a custom UITableViewCell that contains the image.  Then you will provide one image per section to the table view, and you'll implement `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` to provide a view containing the image title. This section header view is the UI element that you describe as staying at the top while scrolling (like in Instagram). You'll probably get pretty familiar with how to implement `UITableView` in the process, so here is some reading to get you started:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials (take a look at the 'How to create a simple iPhone app series, as it deals directly with table views)

http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/  (which talks about making and using custom table view cells)

Good luck!